# Iterate over custom list and Remove item from list conditionally in C#

Tags: c#, list, iterator

I want to iterate over a custom list i.e. defined as:

```
List<CurrentCluster> _curClusters = new List<CurrentCluster>();

IEnumerator<CurrentCluster> _clusIterate = _curClusters.GetEnumerator();
while (_clusIterate.MoveNext())
{
   // Error_01: Cannot implicitly convert CurrentCluster to Cluster
   Cluster _curClus = _clusIterate.Current; // Cluster is base class while  
                                            // CurrentCluster is derived class  
   // Error_02: Does not contain a definition for GetClusterSize()
   if (_curClus.GetClusterSize() == 0)
   {
      // Error_03: Remove(char) has some invalid arguments.
      _clusIterate.ToString().ToList().Remove(_curClus);
   }
}
```

while method `GetClusterSize()` is defined in class `Cluster.cs` as:

```
public int GetClusterSize()  
{  
   return _clusterObjects.Count;  
   // _clusterObjects is a defined in this class as:   
   // List<EvoObject> _clusterObjects = new List<EvoObject>();
}
```

If the size of specific cluster is equal to zero in that cluster list (i.e. `_curClusters` then to remove that cluster from the list.

How can we iterate over a custom list and remove item from list conditionally?

Comment: Yeah I've added comments to make question more understandable

Comment: Actually question is clear from title and a line at bottom that how to iterate over a custom list and remove item conditionally. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just using List `RemoveAll` method and doing this?

```
_curClusters.RemoveAll(_curClus=>_curClus.GetClusterSize() == 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a for loop - you have to work backwards because otherwise you would be moving the elements and some would get skipped.

```
for (int n=_curClusters.Count; n>=0; n--) 
{ 
  if (_curClusters[n].GetClusterSize()==0)  
  {  
     _curClusters.RemoveAt(n);  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing items from a collection using iteration is both advanced and obsolete technique. Use LINQ instead:

```
_curClusters = _curClusters.Where(c => c.GetClusterSize() > 0).ToList();
```

Now `curClusters` contains just "sized clusters", whatever that means.

If you insist to do it through iterations this is the way:

The catch is that you MUST NOT change a collection while iterating over its items. Instead, you can iterate and determine if an item needs to be deleted and mark it somehow - for instance you can add it to another list which contains only items to be deleted. After the first iteration over the original collection, start second one and remove the items from the original, like so:

```
var toBeRemoved = new List<CurrentCluster>();

foreach (var suspiciousCluster in _curCluseters)
{
    if(suspiciousCluster.GetClusterSize() == 0)
    {
        toBeRemoved.Add(suspiciousCluster);
    }
}

foreach (var voidCluser in toBeRemoved)
{
    _curCluster.Remove(voidCluster);
}
```

Again, `_curClusters` contains just "sized clusters", whatever this might mean.

However I highly recommend the first approach.

Comment: I don't think you can do it if you want to filter LinqToEntity by IEnumerable<T>, unless you materialize and recast.

Comment: What `Where` is doing here?

Comment: `Where` is an extension method which could be called against any `IEnumerable<T>`, such  as `List<CurrentCluster>`. In order to use it you need `using System.Linq;`.

Comment: Thanks Bozhidar, now I got the idea as RemoveAll() and Where() almost doing the same trick what longed for

Comment: But here (using `.Where()`) it is giving an error that cannot implicitly convert IEnumerable to List

Comment: You need to call `.ToList()` after `.Where()`. I'm changing my code sample (again).

Comment: @BozhidarStoinev note that the two solutions you are suggesting behave differently: the first creates a new filtered list, the second filter the original list. that can have some side effect if you, e.g, have assigned a reference to the original list to a second variable

Answer (score -1):

I did not understand why you are going with that complexity ... simply you can achieve the goal by below code

```
        List<CurrentCluster> _curClusters = new List<CurrentCluster>();
        _curClusters.RemoveAll(i => i.GetClusterSize()== 0);

        //OR

        for (int i = 0; i < _curClusters.Count; )
        {
            //If you have some more logical checking with CurrentCluster
            //before remove

            if (_curClusters[i].GetClusterSize()== 0)
            {
                _curClusters.Remove(_curClusters[i]);
                continue;
            }

            i++;
        }
```

Comment: The for loop will not work correctly. If you have 4 items in the list, and item 2 and 3 have value 0, then item 2 will be removed, but item 3 will not. This is because by removing item 2, item 3 will go to position of item 2, and therefor will be skipped. Usually the way to do this in a for loop, is to do it in reverse order. See [BugFinders answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37673776/261050).

Comment: @Sinatr I like to give people a chance to correct it before downvoting.